# Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, terraform, bootstrapping, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` to bootstrap some virtual machines in azure.

All examples i've found show using something similar to:

```
settings = <<SETTINGS
    {   
    "fileUris": [ "https://my.bootstrapscript.com/script.sh}" ],
    "commandToExecute": "bash script.sh"
    }
SETTINGS
```

While this works, my issue is i'm having to publicly host `script` for use with `fileUris`. Is there an option within settings that will allow me to send local file contents from my terraform folder?

Something like:

```
settings = <<SETTINGS
    {   
    "file": [ ${file("./script.txt")} ],
    "commandToExecute": "bash script.sh"
    }
SETTINGS
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Yes We Can!

### Introduction

In protected_settings, use "script".

### Scripts

**terraform script**

```
provider "azurerm" {
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmext" {
    resource_group_name     = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    location                = "${var.location}"
    name                    = "${var.hostname}-vmext"

    virtual_machine_name = "${var.hostname}"
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
    type                 = "CustomScript"
    type_handler_version = "2.0"

    protected_settings = <<PROT
    {
        "script": "${base64encode(file(var.scfile))}"
    }
    PROT
}
```

**variables**

```
variable resource_group_name {
    type = string
    default = "ORA"
}

variable location {
    type = string
    default = "eastus"
}

variable hostname {
    type = string
    default = "ora"
}

variable scfile{
    type = string
    default = "yum.bash"
}
```

**bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/download
cd ~/download
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install cowsay
cowsay ExaGridDba
```

### Output

**apply**

```
[terraform@terra stackoverflow]$ terraform apply

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0 will be created
  + resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmex0" {
      + id                   = (known after apply)
      + location             = "eastus"
      + name                 = "ora-vmext"
      + protected_settings   = (sensitive value)
      + publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
      + resource_group_name  = "ORA"
      + tags                 = (known after apply)
      + type                 = "CustomScript"
      + type_handler_version = "2.0"
      + virtual_machine_name = "ora"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Creating...
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m10s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m20s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m30s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m40s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [1m50s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Still creating... [2m0s elapsed]
azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.vmex0: Creation complete after 2m1s [id=/subscriptions/7fe8a9c3-0812-42e2-9733-3f567308a0d0/resourceGroups/ORA/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/ora/extensions/ora-vmext]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

**stdout on the target**

```
[root@ora ~]# cat /var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0/stdout
Preparing...                          ########################################
Updating / installing...
epel-release-7-12                     ########################################
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cowsay.noarch 0:3.04-4.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package          Arch             Version                 Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 cowsay           noarch           3.04-4.el7              epel            42 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 42 k
Installed size: 77 k
Downloading packages:
Public key for cowsay-3.04-4.el7.noarch.rpm is not installed
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : cowsay-3.04-4.el7.noarch                                     1/1
  Verifying  : cowsay-3.04-4.el7.noarch                                     1/1

Installed:
  cowsay.noarch 0:3.04-4.el7

Complete!

< ExaGridDba >
 ------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

### Remarks

1. The script size limit is 262144 bytes base64 encoded, or 196608 bytes.
2. "#!" determines the interpreter. "#!/bin/python" would start a python script.
3. These azurerm_virtual_machine_extension parameters are not required:

   - settings
   - fileUris
   - commandToExecute
   - storageAccountName
   - storageAccountKey
4. protected_settings parameter "script" might not be mentioned in the Terraform documentation. Please refer to  [Use the Azure Custom Script Extension Version 2 with Linux virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux)
5. azurerm_virtual_machine_extension may be used during VM creation, or as a standalone administrative tool.

### Conclusion

In Azure VM, it is possible to run a script without referring to a blob storage account.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks

Comment: How do you pass arguments to the shell script? I am in the same situation, but my bash script has some arguments to pass.

Comment: @getvivekv, 


settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "script": "${base64encode(templatefile("script.sh", {
          arg="test"
        }))}"
    }
SETTINGS

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as commandToExecute made required

Comment: @PavelPikat incorrect. commandToExecute is Microsoft.Compute (Windows VMs) whereas Microsoft.Azure.Extensions is Ubuntu/Linux/OtherAzureOS

Comment: @Lucero79 I think you are mixing many things. Microsoft.Compute is a resource/namespace for VMs (correct), but there's no separation between Windows compute or Linux compute - VMs are generic and can run different images (Windows or Linux), where as extensions exists for both Linux and Window, but there are no specific OS for Azure

Comment: @PavelPikat, sorry, I think it is you who is mistaken, and this is why reading documentation is so important. There is azurerm_virtual_machine which can be any OS, as you say, however, the commandToExecute is native to the Microsoft.Compute namespace extension which ONLY works with Windows OS VMs. There is now a provider differentiation for azurerm_windows_virtual_machine too, to assist in avoiding this confusion moving forward.

Comment: @Lucero79 any supporting argument available for windows(Microsoft.Compute) same as `script`, I have to execute the PS script without external file access.

Answer (score 2):

If you are from the future, here is how to pass multiple arguments to your script:

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The first argument passed is: ${1}"
echo "The first argument passed is: ${2}"
echo "The first argument passed is: ${3}"
```

module.tf

```
module "myVM"{
    # ... rest of your configuration ...
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "custom_script" {
  name                 = "customScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id   = module.myVM.vm-id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  protected_settings = <<PROT
  {
    "script": "${base64encode(templatefile("script.sh", { arg1="1", arg2="2", arg3="3" }))}"
  }
  PROT
  depends_on = [ module.myVM ]
}
```