# Terraform Azure run bash script on VM

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to run a bash script on an Azure VM after deploying it with Terraform. I've tried different approaches but none of them have worked. With "custom_data", I assumed that the file will be uploaded and executed, however I'm not even seeing the file inside the VM.

I've also looked at "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension", but this does not give me the option to upload the file, only to execute commands or download from remote location (can't use fileUris due to requirements):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.test.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "sh my_script.sh"
    }
SETTINGS

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "middleware_vm" {
    name                  = "${var.middleware_vm}"
    location              = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.middleware.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.middleware.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_DS4_v2"        

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "centos_os_disk"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    }

    storage_data_disk {
        name                 = "managed_backup_disk"
        create_option        = "Empty"
        caching              = "ReadWrite"
        disk_size_gb         = "256"  
        managed_disk_type    = "Premium_LRS"
        lun                  = 0
    }

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "OpenLogic"
        offer     = "CentOS"
        sku       = "7.5"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "${var.middleware_vm}"
        admin_username = "middlewareadmin"
        custom_data    = "${file("scripts/middleware_disk.sh")}"
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In azurerm_virtual_machine_extension, you can use:

```
protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
{
    "script": "${base64encode(file(var.scfile))}"
}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
```

Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088476/terraform-azurerm-virtual-machine-extension/58776277?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C41.3406#58776277)

Answer (score 1):

First, the VM extension will just execute the script and do not copy the file to the VM. If you want to copy the script into the VM and then execute it. I will suggest you the [Terraform provisioner `file` and `remote-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html#script-arguments).

Here is the example that copies the file into the existing VM and executes the script:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {

    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "azureuser"
        password = "azureuser@2018"
        host = "13.92.255.50"
        port = 22
    }
    provisioner "file" {
        source = "script.sh"
        destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "/bin/bash /tmp/script.sh"
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: the script should be created in the current directory.

Comment: thanks, however this won't work for us. the VMs cannot be exposed to the internet, that's why I wanted to use "custom_data" or ""azurerm_virtual_machine_extension"

Comment: @MarioJacobo First, there is nothing shows the VM does not expose to the Internet. And you also do not show the exact requirement and which error you got.

Comment: @MarioJacobo If you do not expose the VM to the internet, how do you use the VM?

Comment: there is no error whatsoever, it's just that nothing is ran or uploaded to the VM, using  custom_data    = "${file("scripts/middleware_disk.sh")}". I was hoping to use "custom_data" to upload the file and then "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" to execute the script. The VM just performs some cron tasks internally and does not need to be exposed to the internet at all, due to sensitive data on disk. I may need to use an ARM template (where I encoded the script to base64) and inject that with Terraform. It's not ideal as  but it's the only option I see

Comment: @MarioJacobo If like this, the custom_data is more appropriate. Then you can take a look at [the custom_data in Terraform for the Azure VM](http://teknews.cloud/bootstrapping-azure-vms-with-terraform/).

Comment: thanks, but for some reason "template_file" does not work anymore in > v0.12. I keep getting "<template_file>:104,33-34: Invalid character; This character is not used within the language." very strange

Comment: in the end it worked. had no idea that you have to escape all "$" in the bash file. ended up with "$$", so the rendering worked.

Comment: @MarioJacobo Where do you mean that?

Comment: after a bit more testing, I decided to use ARM template with "azurerm_template_deployment" as "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" or "custom_data"  didnt work. The ARM template can process all bash scripts base64-encoded.